# What's the different between "[]" and "[[]]"

Tags: shell

I dont know that. Thanks for help.
for example:

```
[ $test = 'some string' ] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'


[[ $test = 'some string' ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
```

Comment: See this: * http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031